# How to adjust the zcolor scale in a scatter plot in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, scatter-plot, scatter

I have a data set, contained in three vectors say `xx`, `yy` and `zz`. I want to plot `yy` vs `xx` with the marker color face according to `zz`, so I use the scatter function such as:

```
scatter(xx,yy,50,zz,'s','filled')
```

Unfortunately `zz` has some very extreme values, so I cannot see any difference in the marker face color: all the dots are dark blue!

Is there a possibility to solve this issue? I was thinking of a possibility to impose a lower and an upper value for the color scale, so that any dot with a `zz` value out of the authorized range would be grey (or of the color of the closest bound)...?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try changing the `CLim` property of the axes.

This example uses the MatLab example data `seamount` an changes the colorscale range

- from the original `[-4250  -490]`
- to the new `[-1000 -100]`

Default color scale

```
load seamount
figure
scatter(x,y,5,z)
colorbar
```

Modified color scale

```
figure
scatter(x,y,5,z)
set(gca,'clim',[-1000 -100])
colorbar
```

Default color scale

[image]

Nodified color scale

[image]